# Dropdown Menu keeps disappearing when i hover my cursor on it

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

i was wondering if any of you could help me out, i have started to create a drop down menu for my blog it was going well in my perspective until i realized that the dropdown menu would disapear once i hovered over it with my cursor, the link is fine, but when i hover my cursor over the dropdown menu it disappears.

Source Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Yeti™</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
        <style type="text/css">





        body

                {
            background-image:url(img.jpg);
                background-repeat:no-repeat;


        }

          a:link{color:yellow;
                    text-decoration:none;}
                a:visited{color:yellow;}
                a:hover{background-color:none;
                        color:green;
                                text-decoration:bold;
                                text-decoration:underline;
                                font-weight:bold;}

     #footer {position: absolute;
                   width: 1500px;
                   height: 80px;
                   bottom: 1px;
                   left: 0px;}    

             #main {position: absolute;
                   width: 600px;
                   height: 200px;
                   top: 160px;
                   left: 0px;}


                </style>
        </head>


                                <ul id="nav">



       <div id="Title">
           <p>  Yeti Corporation™  </p>

--------------------------------------------------> ( This is the drop down menu )--------
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navMenu">
           <ul>
           <li><a href="#">top</a>
           <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>

           </ul>

           </li>

           </ul>

                   <ul>
           <li><a href="#">top</a>
           <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>

           </ul>

           </li>

           </ul>

                   <ul>
           <li><a href="#">top</a>
           <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>

           </ul>

           </li>

           </ul>

                   <ul>
           <li><a href="#">top</a>
           <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>

           </ul>

           </li>

           </ul>

                   <ul>
           <li><a href="#">top</a>
           <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>

           </ul>

           </li>

           </ul>

                   <ul>
           <li><a href="#">top</a>
           <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>

           </ul>

           </li>

           </ul>
--------------------------------------------------> ( This is the drop down menu )--------
            </div>
           <body>

           <div id="video">
           <video src="csgo.mp4" width="540" height="380" poster="csgo.jpg" controls></video>
           </div>
                          <div id="main">
                          <div id="yeti">
                <p>     <div id="play">

                           </div></P>
                </div>


                <p>There is never enough to what you can do with programming</p>



                <p> a Small Indie Development company Consisting of 4 people that works on Video games and Websites, as well as many other project we hope to get to in the future. Originally we where two separate companies, but when we realised the potential we had together we decided to merge to create Yeti Corp™.
 If you are interested in Hiring a web developer go to the web development page. If you want to check up on the newest games and software updates, go to the game development page. a Small Indie Development company Consisting of 4 people that works on Video games and Websites, as well as many other project we hope to get to in the future. Originally we where two separate companies, but when we realised the potential we had together we decided to merge to create Yeti Corp™.
 If you are interested in Hiring a web developer go to the web development page. If you want to check up on the newest games and software updates, go to the game development page.  </p>

                </div>   







                </div>







           <div id="footer">
           <a href="#" />Contact Us|</a>
           <a href="#" />Web Dev|</a>
           <a href="#" />Game Dev|</a>
           <a href="#" />Graphic Designer|</a>
           <a href="#" />Twitter Page|</a>
           <a href="#" />FaceBook Page|</a>
           <a href="#" />Gmail Page</a>
       <p> All Rights Reserver Yeti LTD. 2014 Created by Head Web Developer, Hamza Issa</P>
       </div>      
                        </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#body{
    background: white;
}


#wrapper{
    font:20px Tahoma;
}
--------------------------------------------------> ( This is the drop down menu )--------

#navMenu{
    margin:0;
    padding:30;
}

#navMenu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
}

#navMenu li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background:#999;
}

#navMenu li ul a {
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:20px Tahoma;
    height:30px;
    width:130px;
    display:block;
    color: blue;
    border:1px solid black;

}

#navMenu ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:30px;
}


#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    visibility:visible;
    display: block;
}
--------------------------------------------------> ( This is the drop down menu )--------


#Title{
    font: 30px  Candara;
        -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(110,110,110,.4) 10px 10px 10px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 100px;
        color: orange;
}

#Search{

    margin-left: 200px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#Links{

    padding-left: 400px;
        font: bold 20px Tahoma;
     padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#Links a:hover{
  color: green;

}

#sign{
    color: white;
        font:20px Tahoma ;
        padding-right: 100px;
        padding-top: px;
}

#Sign_up{
    padding-left: 400px;
        padding-bottom: 200px;

}



#main{

   font: 14px Courier ;
   color: white;
   width: 650px;
   padding-left: 100px;

}

#yeti{
   font: 45px  Candara ;


}

#footer{
   background: #E6EAEE;
   color: black;
   font: 20px impact;
   text-align: center;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   padding-right: 60px;
   width: 1300px;
}

#video{
   padding-left: 850px;
   padding-top: 50px;


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Post your code here :)

Comment: Wait so what should i do,  I am unable to post it in the comments being that it is to long

Comment: update your question, you can edit it

Comment: Okay, I know i can edit it but what should i edit about it, the link works

Comment: copy the code from the link and paste it in the question. see what paulie said.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include **just enough** code to reproduce the issue. We don't need all the fancy styling, fonts, gradients, images etc. Just the basic MENU HTML & CSS that makes it all work (or not).

Comment: Can someone please just answer my question, I know your trying to help but I'm finding this all difficult, i just want someone to help me solve my problem, it may be simple in your point of view but not in mine ( I'm 13yr)

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the behaviour you're describing, when I hover on the link 'top' I see the link 'recipe' which is what I would expect. [Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/u0tvmm7r/)

Answer (score 0):

So I made a simplified version of your code (In the future you should do this first) and was able to narrow down the problem.  The positioning of your `#main` section is messing with the drop downs and it appears on top of them. So the simple thing I did was add `z-index` to the drop downs

```
#navMenu ul li ul {
  position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
  top:30px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
  // display: block;
  visibility:visible;
  // display: block; 
}
```

```css
a:link {
    color:yellow;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 10px;
}
a:visited {
    color:yellow;
}
a:hover {
    background-color:none;
    color:green;
    text-decoration:bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#Title {
    font: 30px Candara;
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(110, 110, 110, .4) 10px 10px 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    color: orange;
}
#wrapper {
    font:20px Tahoma;
}
#navMenu {
    margin:0;
    padding:30;
}
#navMenu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
}
#navMenu li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background:#999;
}
#navMenu li ul a {
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:20px Tahoma;
    height:30px;
    width:130px;
    display:block;
    color: blue;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#navMenu ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}
#main {
    font: 14px Courier;
    color: red;
    padding-left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 160px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Title">
    <p>Yeti Corporation™</p>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="navMenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">top</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">top</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div id="main">
            <p>There is never enough to what you can do with programming</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```